# Mule Dataweaver int array to xml elements soap

Tags: arrays, xml, soap, mule, dataweave

I have a problem converting an array of integers to xml in MuleESB.

So I have an Object called `UsagePoint` which contains `groups=ArrayOfint [_int=[2]]`

In my transform component [Transform Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuBir.png) i have tried the following tranforming approaches, it is on purpose I have left out the `ns0 namespace`:

```
%namespace ns1 http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays
%type groups = :object {class: "xmlinterface.ArrayOfint"}
--    
 ns0#Groups: {
    ns1#int: payload.groups.int as :object
 },
```

and

```
%namespace ns1 http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays
    %type groups = :object {class: "xmlinterface.ArrayOfint"}
    --    
     ns0#Groups: payload.groups map {
        ns1#int: payload.groups.int as :object
     },
```

and

```
%namespace ns1 http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays
--    
  ns0#Groups: {
     ns1#int: payload.groups
  },
```

and where I set a flow variable `groupint` just before the transformer component by getting the array using the following method calls `payload.getGroups().getInt()` the result is `[2]` and I'm getting a deserialization error Int32.

```
%namespace ns1 http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays
--    
  ns0#Groups: {
    ns1#int: flowVars.groupint
  },
```

But when I call `payload.getGroups().getInt()[0]` such that I get my integer, it works fine. My problem is that there can be more elements in the array than just one. So I want a result that says:

```
  <Groups>
    <int>1</int>
    <int>2</int>
    <int>3</int>
    ...
  </Groups>
```

and not a result that only can contain 1 int element in the resulting xml.

I have also tried just to say `ns0#Groups: payload.groups`. So how do I write a Dataweaver expression that handles an array of ints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
%namespace ns1 http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays
%type groups = :object {class: "xmlinterface.ArrayOfint"}
--    
 ns0#Groups: {
    (payload.groups.int map {ns1#int: $})
 }
```

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#dynamic-elements